# Getting a lot of of "Unassigned" traffic in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, web-traffic

I need help in our Google Analytics traffic. The number of "unassigned" traffic gets manyier month by month.

What could be wrong in here?

Is there a way I would know which website or which sources provide the 'unassigned' traffic?

Is there a way to fix this? How can I fix this?

I have checked the google analytics code of the website and I believe it is correct because I copy pasted it from GA4 itself and put it in the head section of our website.

I also checked the GA4 Traffic Acquisition Reporting to dig down the "unassigned" ones and set the Session default channel group to only filter "Unassigned" then setting the 2nd filter Session Source/Medium and I can see (not set) as the Source/Medium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a wonderfull tutorial to fix unassigned values.

https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/unassigned-in-google-analytics-4/